# Stuck with POST MULTI PART FORM DATA - Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am stuck with post multipart form data in xamarin.forms. When I tried with POSTMAN its all works fine but not with my code in xamarin.forms. I dont know what is wrong with the code. I am using a library calling [RestSharp port as PCL and for .NET Core](https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable).

Here is the POSTMAN code

```
    var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.2.126:86/Appointment.svc/UploadFileios");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "11a61861-ed9c-2f35-751b-6b615907c269");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"phone\"\r\n\r\n81234518\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"address\"\r\n\r\nAddress Dummy House\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"confpassword\"\r\n\r\n123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"\r\n\r\nAlex Chengalan Paily\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

and below is my code with xamarin.forms.

```
    var client = new RestClient(url);
                    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                    string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
                    //string boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";
                    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
                    request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
                    string name = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;


                    string formdataTemplate = "--" + boundary +
                        "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}\r\n";
                    string formitem = null;
                    foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
                    {
                        formitem = formitem + string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine("Items: " + formitem);
                    request.AddParameter(name, formitem, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = await client.Execute(request);
```

But I am getting a parse error here from server. Please help me on this situation.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Its a parse exception which triggered from backend, which is a custom message.

Comment: Can you share parse error message? May be this link will help you [Multipart Form Post in C#](https://briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c/)

Answer (score 3):

I´m not familiar enough with RestSharp library, but here is a working sample supporting a file stream and other variables without any 3rd party dependencies and working in Xamarin.Forms from a PCL (note that you don´t need to mess with boundaries manually):

```
try
{
    var file = await PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.GetFileAsync(device.ClientCodePhoto);
    using(Stream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.Read))
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    using(var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        content.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), "client_code_image", "upload.jpg");

        var values = new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_code", device.ClientCode),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("registered_by", device.RegisteredBy),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("notes", device.Notes ?? string.Empty),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sim_code", device.SimCode),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("qr_codes", device.QrCodes)
        };

        foreach(var keyValuePair in values)
            content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), string.Format("\"{0}\"", keyValuePair.Key));

        using(var result = await client.PostAsync($"{Constants.Server}devices/", content))
        {
            var input = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // do something with the result 
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    // something went wrong
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Depends on the content you want to pass across to the endpoint.
This works:

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("https://" + "www.url.com");
                    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
                    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
                    using (MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                        KeyValuePair<string, string>[] values = new[]
                                                  {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("attachment", ""),

        };





                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in values)
                        {
                            content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value), string.Format("\"{0}\"", keyValuePair.Key));
                        }

                        //for cookies
                        cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("name", "value"));



                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-G960F Build/R16NW) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile Safari/537.36");
                        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DNT", "1");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", "https://www.url.com");

                        string finalUrl = "/url";


                        using (HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(finalUrl, content))
                        {
                            string input = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```